# null reference exception in site.master.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net

i got "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". in my master page code behind. how to solve this?

Site.Master.Cs

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["IsLogin"] == "1")
        {
            ((HyperLink)HeadLoginView.FindControl("Login")).Visible = false;
            ((HyperLink)HeadLoginView.FindControl("Logout")).Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ((HyperLink)HeadLoginView.FindControl("Login")).Visible = true;
            ((HyperLink)HeadLoginView.FindControl("Logout")).Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Site.master

```
 <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    [ <a href="~/Default.aspx" id="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                     [ <a href="~/Logout.aspx" id="HeadLoginStass" runat="server">Log Out</a> ]
                </AnonymousTemplate>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you try to locate your controls is off. The `HeadLoginView.FindControl("Login"))` comes back as null and your further attempt to set `Visible` on it blows up

You should type your control id exactly as it shows up in the page definition `HeadLoginStatus' for the login button I assume

Answer (score 0):

If your session object not set before used you get this error .

```
 if (Session["IsLogin"] != null && Session["IsLogin"].ToString() == "1")
{
   // your current code
}
else
{
   // your current code.
}
```

Comment: there is no need to add this extra check - it will work the same way without it. I hate the 'just in case' checks for null - they do nothing but bloat the code